# Map a return type as the union of an input type and a list of property values from an array in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a function that I have declared as follows:

```
export const buildLocalizedInfo = <T extends { id: number }, U extends { target: string }>(
    recordBuilder: (record: any) => T,
    propsMapper: readonly U[],
): T
```

and that I use like this:

```
const bounties = buildLocalizedInfo(
    (record) => ({
        id: record['m_ID'],
    }),
    [{ target: 'name' }],
);
```

I want to have the return type of `buildLocalizedInfo` to be `T & {name: string}`, except that it should also extends to whatever properties I pass in the input array.

For instance,

```
const bounties = buildLocalizedInfo(
    (record) => ({
        id: record['m_ID'],
        other: record['other'],
    }),
    [{ target: 'name' }, { target: 'description' }],
);
```

should resolve `bounties` to be of type `{ id: string; other: string; name: string; description: string}`.

Is this possible in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to intersect the result with a mapped type of the elements, but since you're mapping them all to strings, a `Record` will do just fine:

```
export const buildLocalizedInfo = <T extends { id: number }, U extends { target: string }>(
    recordBuilder: (record: any) => T,
    propsMapper: readonly U[],
): T & Record<U["target"], string>;
```

---

However, you'll probably need `as const` with this. If you don't like that, then you can use this instead:

```
type Narrow<T> =
    | (T extends infer U ? U : never)
    | Extract<T, number | string | boolean | bigint | symbol | null | undefined | []>
    | ([T] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof T]: Narrow<T[K]> });

export const buildLocalizedInfo = <T extends { id: number }, U extends readonly { target: string }[]>(
    recordBuilder: (record: any) => T,
    propsMapper: Narrow<U>,
): T & Record<U[number]["target"], string>;
```

This `Narrow` utility will narrow the type for us, which you can see [here](https://tsplay.dev/NDRbVW).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Calling it with `buildLocalizedInfo((record) => ({ id: record['m_ID'] }), [{ target: 'name'}] )` infers the results to `({ id: any; } & Record<string, string>)` instead of `{id: any; name: string}`.

Comment: @SébastienTromp Right, but if you use `as const` it would work. But I don't think `as const` is necessary either; see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is working like a charm! I will need to take some time to wrap my head around all of this though :D